# WooCommerce Theme Integration

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to integrate WooCommerce into my current theme. Most of the pages work except for the ones that use my page.php template. I tried following the integration guide here:

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

However, my page.php doesn't include the normal loop.

Here's my page.php template:

```
<?php 
    if( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_general_page_layout', true) ) {
        get_template_part('layout', get_post_meta($post->ID, '_general_page_layout', true) );
    } else {
        get_template_part('layout', theme_options('page', 'default_layout', 'full-width') );
    }
?>
```

So I'm not sure how to integrate WooCommerce support.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the woocommerce support your template would look like this:

```
<?php 
    <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
?>
```